# Why object of class GuzzleHttp\Client could not be converted to string?

Tags: php, oauth, guzzle

This is my method

```
class MyClass 
{
  protected client; 
  public function setCl($clientArg)
  {
    // check for invalid argument type - client has to be a guzzle client
    if ($clientArg.get_class() != $this->client.get_class() ||
      !($clientArg instanceof GuzzleHttp\Client))
      throw new InvalidArgumentException("Argument type must be of Guzzle client");

    $this->client = $clientArg;
  }
}
```

The test has invoked this method as such:

```
class TestClass extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase 
{
  protected $myClass
  public function testSetCl() {
    $cl = new Client();
    $res = $this->myClass->setCl($cl); // why does a setter need to return something?

    $this->assertInstanceOf(Client::class, $res);
  }
}
```

The error posted in the title is what I receive when I run the test. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Reason this occurred is the line:

```
$clientArg.get_class() != $this->client.get_class()
```

In PHP, the . is a concatenation, therefore when changed to:

```
$clientArg->get_class() != $this->client->get_class()
```

This works.